# The SU binary must be updated

Tags: root-access, superuser

Xiaomi redmi 2 runs MIUI 6.2.4.0(KHJCNBK)

I ran a zip file in CWM, and had a success `done!`:

[image]

Then installed SuperSU from google play, it wanted to update binary, so I clicked `normal`. It said failed and wanted me to reboot. I did, tried the second option (CWM). It says `SuperSu will attempt to reboot`. I click `ok` and nothing happens. What's the way out?

Comment: In the second option, the app is supposed to reboot into Recovery and do some flashing on its own. Try using that CWM/TWRP option again and if it doesn't reboot then reboot into recovery manually , find the option to update su binaries and execute it. Usually a modern recovery will give you this option when you try to reboot the device from it. This app (though great) is sometimes a mess. I'm aware of this issue. Also, could you share the link where you read this rooting technique? I need to see something.

Answer (score 2):

Reboot into recovery after copying this file into root of your SD card. Flash this file using a custom recovery like CWM . Reboot phone. Check for SuperSu in your app drawer.

[SuperSu 2.46](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip?retrieve_file=1)